# SoupPVP RIGHT_CLICK_AIR?

Tags: java, minecraft

Hallo Leute Ich wollte ein Minecraft Plugin Programmieren,
dabei ist mir ein Fehler auf gefallen.

Hello I wanted to program a Minecraft plugin, and I noticed a mistake.

```
public void onIteract(PlayerInteractEvent e) {
        try {
            
            if(e.getAction().equals(Action.RIGHT_CLICK_AIR)|| e.getAction().equals(Action.RIGHT_CLICK_BLOCK)) {
                Player p = e.getPlayer();
                ItemStack bowl = new ItemStack(Material.BOWL);
                if(e.getMaterial() == Material.MUSHROOM_SOUP) {
                    double i = p.getHealth();
                    if(i != 20) {
                        if(i > 11) {
                            p.setHealth(20);
                            p.getInventory().setItemInHand(bowl);
                            p.playSound(p.getLocation(), Sound.EAT, 1, 1);
                        } else {
                            p.setHealth(i + 8);
                            p.getInventory().setItemInHand(bowl);
                            p.playSound(p.getLocation(), Sound.EAT, 1, 1);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
    }catch (Exception exception) {
            
        }
    }
```

und zwar funktioniert dieser code ohne Probleme aber wen ich die soup "MUSHROOM_SOUP" in der Luft rechst klick funktioniert `p.getInventory().setItemInHand(bowl);` nicht zumindest bekomme ich sie nicht gesetzt.

this code works without problems but when I right click the soup "MUSHROOM_SOUP" in the air it works `p.getInventory().setItemInHand(bowl);` at least I don't get it set.

Danke bei der Hilfe ;)
MC-Version: 1.8.9 / Spigot

Comment: i added a comment i hope you understand me

Comment: Your question is not clear, what the results you want, please try to add some explanations

Comment: Please write your question in english as StackOverflow is an english-only site.

Answer (score 0):

Here are the issues with your code:

1. Don't catch all exceptions without a reason to. If an exception is thrown in your onInteract method, then there is something wrong with your code.
2. `a.equals(b)` is to compare Strings, use `a == b` for objects other than Strings.
3. You spelt `onInteract` incorrectly.
4. More of a nitpick, but you should name variables with words, not just letters.
5. `e.getMaterial()` isn't a valid method. You need to access the player's inventory, get the ItemStack in their hand, and get the Material (type) of the item.
6. The big block limiting the health to `20` is unnecessary, when you can set the health to `Math.min(20, value)`. This forces the health to be set no higher than `20`.

I haven't tested this, but I believe this will work.

```
public void onInteract(final PlayerInteractEvent event) {
    if(event.getAction() == Action.RIGHT_CLICK_AIR || event.getAction() == Action.RIGHT_CLICK_BLOCK) {
        final Player player = event.getPlayer();
        if(player.getInventory().getItemInHand().getType() == Material.MUSHROOM_SOUP) {
            player.setHealth(Math.min(20, player.getHealth() + 8));
            player.playSound(player.getLocation(), Sound.EAT, 1, 1);
            p.getInventory().setItemInHand(new ItemStack(Material.BOWL, 1));
        }
    }
}
```

Ways you can improve this further:

- Instead of using the number `20`, get the player's max health, as it could be higher than `20` on some servers.
- Play a particle, i.e. the one from mushroom soup, when it is consumed.
- Add hunger points to the player.

Feel free to contact me on SpigotMC (@lokka30) if you wish to contact me - I rarely check this website.